# Html.ClientValidation doesnt works on mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I am trying to work out client side validation and have followed a couple of tutorials , it looks quite simple but i have no idea why its not working on my project, below is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js"></script>

    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary("Please Correct the errors and try again")%>

    <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.test,"Test") %>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.test)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.test)%>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
```

edited:
master page

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js") %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.js") %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js") %>"> </script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ie6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any ideas Why the client side validation doesnt works when I press tab for that field.

Comment: yeh but I am not using razor engine

Comment: I also tried url.content for the scripts but that doest work ..

Comment: Have you used something like Fiddler to make sure that it actually is finding your script files? Also: boo! Use razor :)

Comment: will use razor in the next project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC 3, `jquery` and `jquery.validate` are the default frameworks for doing client side validation. So modify your code to look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js") %>"></script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Please Correct the errors and try again") %>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.test, "Test") %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.test) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.test) %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Things to notice:

- Using jQuery 1.5.1 which is the default one bundled with ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM and the Tools Update. Make sure you use a later version of jQuery as IIRC there was some incompatibility between the jquery.validate plugin and the jquery version.
- Using `jquery.validate.js`
- Using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` which unobtrusively attaches the jQuery.validate plugin to HTML5 data-* attributes emitted by the Html helpers.
- Using the `Url.Content` helper to reference static resources instead of hardcoding their locations.
- No more need to call `Html.EnableClientValidation()`
- No more need to include any javascript that starts with the prefix `Microsoft*`

One final note: make sure that in your web.config unobtrusive client script validation is enabled:

```
<appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

The best way to get the latest versions of those scripts is to install the [ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208140), create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the default wizard in Visual Studio and fetch those 3 scripts.

Comment: where can i get jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Comment: It should come included in the default Internet project template. That is, when you create a new MVC 3 project, you will have a few options: Internet Application, Intranet Application (if you installed the MVC 3 Tools Update) and Empty I believe. If you choose Internet it should be included in your Scripts folder.

Comment: its not included in the mvc3 bundle

Comment: @Mr A, install the ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update and create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application. You will get all you need there.

Comment: @thnx Darin for always being there for mvc questions, it would have been a nightmare for me , if you would have not been helping me with these silly queries on mvc

Comment: @Mr A, I am always glad when I can help people that have the determination to learn something. There are no silly questions.

Comment: I have followed what you mentioned above but still the client side validation is not working :(

Comment: @Mr A, are you getting some javascript error in the FireBug console? Did you make sure that the 3 files are properly present in the `scripts` folder: `jquery-1.5.1.js`, `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`. Be careful because jquery might have already been included in your master template and you are including it twice.

Comment: If it's still not working then I would try and look at Fiddler/Firebug to make sure that the script files are actually getting downloaded. If they are then perhaps post your entire view so we can see if there is something else wrong. Like Darin said you might be referencing your script files twice, etc.

Comment: I have edited the question above , with scripts sequence in the masterpage . and i m not using it twice , just using in masterpage

Comment: @Mr A, so are there any js errors in the console? Is `ClientValidationEnabled` set to true in your web.config?

Comment: @Dismissile Just checked through firebug all the scripts are loaded

Comment: yeh i did that in webconfig and there are no errors in console too

Comment: I am not calling Html.EnableClientValidation(); as Darin mentioned above we dont need to call in mvc 3

Comment: @Mr A, can you email me a sample project where the problem exhibits so that I can take a look at what's wrong?

Comment: We might need a little more information then. Are you getting server side validation working? How are you implementing the server side validation? With DataAnnotations?

Comment: yeh server side works fine , i m using DataAnnotation for that